# Performance comparison of Insertion sort Vs Java's Collections.sort()

Tags: java, sorting, collections

In my complexity sensitive application, I tried profiling the performance of `Insertion sort` and Java's `Collections.sort()` by iteratively measuring the time required to sort by both these ways.
I used below `Insertion sort` logic

```
 void applyInsertionSort(ArrayList<Integer> list0) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(list0);
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int eleToBeSorted = list.get(i);
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (eleToBeSorted < list.get(j - 1)) {
                int temp = list.get(j - 1);
                list.set(j - 1, eleToBeSorted);
                list.set(j, temp);
            }
        }
    }
    long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    insSortTime.add((double) elapsed / 1000000); //Record elapsed time(Millis)
    return list;
}
```

In another method I used `Collections.sort()`

```
void applyCollectionsSort(ArrayList<Integer> list0) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(list0);
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    Collections.sort(list);
    long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    collSortTime.add((double) elapsed / 1000000); //Record elapsed time(Millis)
    return list;
}
```

Then I iteratively(2000 iterations) called these methods independently by shuffling the elements in original `list` at the end of every iteration.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        applyInsertionSort(list);
        applyCollectionsSort(list);
        Collections.shuffle(list);
 }
```

[image]

I have following questions

1. Why in the very first iteration `Collections.sort()` took comparatively much longer time to sort?
2. why the performance of `Collections.sort()` is degraded in the middle portion of the series as shown in graph, even since according to Java [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)), `Collections.sort()` uses optimized version of merge sort offering the guranteed performance of `n logn`?

Comment: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: Don't you want to shuffle the list before `Collections.sort ` as well?

Comment: Shouldn't this: `applyInsertionSort(list); applyCollectionsSort(list);      Collections.shuffle(list);` be this: `Collections.shuffle(list); applyInsertionSort(list); Collections.shuffle(list);     applyCollectionsSort(list);` (As is, you are tryin to sort a sorted array)?

Comment: @npinti No. In method body, I am creating a new list everytime.

Comment: If I am understanding your code, what you have are multiple pointers looking at the same memory location which in the end resolves to the same list.

Comment: @npinti Well, I even tried copying individual element from the original list to the method specific private list and then applied sorting. Also I put `Collections.shuffle()` in between two method calls, but even then I got similar results.

Comment: @pbabcdefp I tried that as well, but I got the similar behavior. No change.

Comment: Ah I see. You're never actually sorting `list`. Apologies. `Collections.sort` has worst case time complexity `O(n log n)` whereas for your sort algorithm it's `O(n^2)`, so for larger and larger lists `Collections.sort` will win.